# RSA with large key size Encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, rsa, padding

I'm trying to encrypt an array of 256 bytes by using RSACryptoServiceProvider but I'm getting an exception of "Bad Length" each time.

```
byte[] seed = new byte[256];
byte[] cypherSeed = new byte[256];

RNGCryptoServiceProvider gen = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
gen.GetBytes(seed);

using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2560))
{
   RSAParameters param = new RSAParameters();
   param.Exponent = this.exponent;
   param.Modulus = this.modulus;

   // set public keys
   rsaCryptoServiceProvider.ImportParameters(param);
   cypherSeed = rsaCryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt(seed, false);
}
```

What am I doing wrong??!!

Comment: btw. your code is unnecessarily slow. The way you're creating `RSACryptoServiceProvider` causes the creation of a 2560 bit key, which is very slow (unless .net recently made that a lazy initialization, like mono).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to account for the padding. The message size is smaller than the key size because RSA needs the rest of the block for padding.

If you use PKCS#1 v1.5 padding, you need 11 bytes of padding, if you use the stronger OAEP padding, you need 2*hashsize + 2 bytes as padding.

See [RSACryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.encrypt.aspx)

You should also consider using hybrid encryption, where you encrypt a random key with RSA, and the actual message with that key.

Comment: So what can I do? my Modulus size is 256 bytes.

Comment: @user1478102 Depends on what your requirements are. I'd use hybrid encryption.

Comment: I'm kind of re-implementing existing code which was written some years ago in C++. in the original code they used open ssl and the RSA_public_encrypt function was call with RSA_NO_PADDING, meaning no padding!! Is there a way of bypassing the padding in the Encrypt function??

Comment: @user1478102 In that case you can use `BigInteger.ModPow(message, exponent, modulus)`. Note that this causes at least two issues: 1) Paddingless RSA is insecure in many situations 2) If you do the same for the private key operation `BigInteger.ModPow(ciphertext, decryptionExponent, modulus)`, you'll open up timing attacks.